# Formatting timestamp in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Updated at : `{{res.updated_at}}`

Value:   `{"updated_at":"2017-04-12T21:46:20Z"}`

I need to change this `2017-04-12T21:46:20Z` to `2017-04-12 21:46:20` by removing `T` and `Z`. Please help how to achieve this. The code is in angular js.

Comment: Try: `d = "2017-04-12T21:46:20Z"; d=d.replace(/[T]/, ' ');d=d.replace(/[Z]/, ''); `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to:

```
{{res.updated_at| date : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Detail format at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's specific to angular, but this formatting pattern should work.

`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

This should format the date as `2017-04-12 21:46:20`

Answer (score -1):

```
"2017-04-12T21:46:20Z".split("T").join(" ").split("Z").join("")
```